# Is the Mahr only allowed to be handed to the wife exclusively?

Tags: nikah, mehr

Can the Mahr be handed over to the wife's family or it can only be handed directly to the wife? If it can be handed over to the family, are there any conditions upon it?

Comment: This could rather be a case sensitive matter.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Are the cases different depending upon the age of wife?

Comment: that might be a point. My understanding is that mahr or sadaq etc. is a right of the wife. But this depends also on whether or not she is able to handle with it and culture may also play a role.